# How is the noise in the forward process in Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models computed?

Tags: generative-model, image-generation

The inputs are decayed towards the origin using this formula within Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models (DDPMs):

$$q\left(\mathbf{x}_{1: T} \mid \mathbf{x}_0\right):=\prod_{t=1}^T q\left(\mathbf{x}_t \mid \mathbf{x}_{t-1}\right), \quad q\left(\mathbf{x}_t \mid \mathbf{x}_{t-1}\right):=\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{x}_t ; \sqrt{1-\beta_t} \mathbf{x}_{t-1}, \beta_t \mathbf{I}\right)$$

I however do not understand how the origin is determined. How is the noise in the forward process or diffusion process computed? In the original [DDPM paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf) it is only stated that:

> the forward process variances $β_t$ can be learned by reparameterization [33] or held constant as hyperparameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a noise $\epsilon_t$ by sampling a distribution (which you already explicitly stated as $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}_t; \sqrt{1-\beta_t}\mathbf{x}_{t-1}, \beta_t\mathbf{I})$) during the *sampling phase*. The "origin" is the standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I})$, which is a constant instead of a variable ground truth to learn.

The variable ground truth to learn (using a U-Net) during the *training phase* is rather the noise $\epsilon_t$ added during the sampling phase. Reverse to the diffusion (sampling) process, the noise $\epsilon_t$, when subtracted from the noisier $\mathbf{x}_{t}$, can produce a less noisy $\mathbf{x}_{t+1}$. Therefore, **given $\mathbf{x}_{t}$**, the noise $\epsilon_t$ encodes certain information regarding the input data $\mathbf{x}_{T}$.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate on that? I still do not understand how the origin is determined, is it the distribution of the input data point during the specific time point?

Comment: @Mariusmarten I edited the answer. Maybe you confuse origin with ground truth. Diffusion models are intuitively different from traditional neural networks due to the additional *sampling phase*.